# Angular 2 template is not reflecting data retrieved from server

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I'm having an issue with Angular 2 is not reflecting the data I retrieve from the server in my template.
The component retrieves details of a result-item by calling a webapi.

The component retrieves details of a result-item by calling a webapi.
Logging to the console shows that the data is actually retrieved successfully but the template doesn't reflect the data is has retrieved.
What am i doing wrong?

Below the code of my component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'as-resultdata-details',
    template: '
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <span [innerHtml]="resultdata.name">
            TEST name
        </span>
    '
})
export class DataServiceItemDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    public resultdata: IResultData;

    constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private dataService: DataService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.params
            .map(params => params['itemId'])
            .subscribe((itemId) => {
                this.getDataFromService(itemId);
        });
    }    
    private getDataFromService(itemId: number) {
        this.dataService.getDataFromService(itemId)
            .subscribe((resultdata: IResultData) => {
                this.resultdata = resultdata;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: try and log resultdata in the subscribe to see the structure of the returned data. Also you might want to add an ngif in the span binding to resultdata.name since .name will not be available until the results are loaded by the service.

Comment: Try adding `<div>{{resultdata | json}}</div>` to the template and post what it shows.

Comment: I have logged resultdata coming back from the server and the data is not the problem it seems. When using console.log or outputting the json like Gunter below suggests is get the json i expect but when i try to output the field directly i get nothing. When i add another property to the component: public status: string and set it's value in the .subscribe to this.resultdata.name and use it in the template i actually get the value i want.

Comment: I have figured out the issue and it's actually quite simple. The cause of the issue is that i am using resultdata in my view before it has been bound to some actual data. So
`<span [innerHtml]="resultdata.name">`
results in an error.

So adding an check via ngIf around <span> above makes sure the error is no longer raised and is updated as soon as the requested data is returned:

`<div *ngIf="resultdata">
    <span [innerHtml]="resultdata.name">Test name</span>
</div>`